# iOS images sizes

Tags: ios

I'm having doubts regarding the size of the images at different resolutions.

**Example:**

I have a button in the GUI I inserted it in size 100x50.
My background pictures for this button to 1x, 2x, 3x must be of sizes which? In px or pt?

I did some tests and insert them for their size 100x50 1x, 2x and 3x 300x150 200x100 (in px). But the images were of poor quality.

**PS:** I've seen the documentation but also those doubts were not very clear

Comment: Did you use Images.xcassets? If not check if you named the images correctly e.g. `image@1x.png`, `image@2x.png`, `image@3x.png` (@1x is optional).

Comment: @limfinity, do you really name the x1 image `image@1x.png`? As for my knowledte its name should be just `image.png`.

Comment: Yes, i named: image@1x.png, image@2x.png, image@3x.png

Comment: @limfinity Yes i use Images.xcassets

Comment: When you use the asset catalogue then you don't have to care for the naming conventions.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Could post a reply with a detailed explanation on this?

Comment: @HermannKlecker as I wrote @1x is optional. It would be still named "image" when you're using something like `imageNamed:@"image"`. @Gian could you share your images with us? Is the size of the button at runtime correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

- 1x - 100*50px - image.png
- 2x - 200*100px - image@2x.png
- 3x - 300*150px - image@3x.png

Comment: As simple as that. But the naming conventions must be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with naming better you Use the assets catalog. Xcode will manage the @1x, @2x, @3x easilly  or name the images properly as

- image_name.png (for 1x image)
- image_name@2x.png
- image_name@3x.png

for more details about image resolutions take a looks on [this](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) and [apple's ui guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple vector graphic, png or icns format. Now there a different options to convert your picture in hte @2 and @3 format. You can use e.g. the App 'Prepro' -> it's for free in the App Store. This App will create your needed icons